# Set a "basic size" for geom_label in ggplot2 so that minimal value is still readable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use "size" as an aesthetic in `geom_label`. My problem is that the minimum label size is so small that the corresponding label is barely readable.

Is there a way to set something like a "minimal size" when using the size aesthetic? If there is a way, it should also work to specify a maximum label size, right?

I tried the `theme_minimal(base_size = 15)`, but this changes all the sizes in the plot.

Small reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(title = c("too small!!!", "just right", "quite big"),
                   x.value = 1:3,
                   y.value = 1:3,
                   size.value = c(1, 5, 10))
ggplot(data, aes(x = x.value, y = y.value, size = size.value, label = title)) +
  geom_label()
```

[image: Example plot with the label in the lower-left too small]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There indeed as a way using `scale_size` and the `range` parameter:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x.value, y = y.value, size = size.value, label = title)) +
  geom_label() + scale_size(range = c(0.5, 6))
```

[image]